# Jquery Jcrop Selection

Tags: jquery, jcrop

don't know what happened in my jcrop selection. I think I pressed some keys in my keyboard that made the handles of the selection from squares into dots. Im using mozilla firefox as my browser.

[image]


The original handle must appear square as shown below. 


[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The squares are part of the css.  The default css that comes with it is like so:

```
.jcrop-holder{direction:ltr;text-align:left}
.jcrop-vline,.jcrop-hline{background:#FFF url(Jcrop.gif) top left repeat;font-size:0;position:absolute}
.jcrop-vline{height:100%;width:1px!important}
.jcrop-hline{height:1px!important;width:100%}
.jcrop-vline.right{right:0}
.jcrop-hline.bottom{bottom:0}
.jcrop-handle{background-color:#333;border:1px #eee solid;font-size:1px}
.jcrop-tracker{-webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent;-webkit-touch-callout:none;-webkit-user-select:none;height:100%;width:100%}
.jcrop-handle.ord-n{left:50%;margin-left:-4px;margin-top:-4px;top:0}
.jcrop-handle.ord-s{bottom:0;left:50%;margin-bottom:-4px;margin-left:-4px}
.jcrop-handle.ord-e{margin-right:-4px;margin-top:-4px;right:0;top:50%}
.jcrop-handle.ord-w{left:0;margin-left:-4px;margin-top:-4px;top:50%}
.jcrop-handle.ord-nw{left:0;margin-left:-4px;margin-top:-4px;top:0}
.jcrop-handle.ord-ne{margin-right:-4px;margin-top:-4px;right:0;top:0}
.jcrop-handle.ord-se{bottom:0;margin-bottom:-4px;margin-right:-4px;right:0}
.jcrop-handle.ord-sw{bottom:0;left:0;margin-bottom:-4px;margin-left:-4px}
.jcrop-dragbar.ord-n,.jcrop-dragbar.ord-s{height:7px;width:100%}
.jcrop-dragbar.ord-e,.jcrop-dragbar.ord-w{height:100%;width:7px}
.jcrop-dragbar.ord-n{margin-top:-4px}
.jcrop-dragbar.ord-s{bottom:0;margin-bottom:-4px}
.jcrop-dragbar.ord-e{margin-right:-4px;right:0}
.jcrop-dragbar.ord-w{margin-left:-4px}
.jcrop-light .jcrop-vline,.jcrop-light .jcrop-hline{background:#FFF;filter:Alpha(opacity=70)!important;opacity:.70!important}
.jcrop-light .jcrop-handle{-moz-border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;background-color:#000;border-color:#FFF;border-radius:3px}
.jcrop-dark .jcrop-vline,.jcrop-dark .jcrop-hline{background:#000;filter:Alpha(opacity=70)!important;opacity:.7!important}
.jcrop-dark .jcrop-handle{-moz-border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px;background-color:#FFF;border-color:#000;border-radius:3px}
.jcrop-holder img,img.jcrop-preview{max-width:none}
```

You also need the Jcrop.gif file that is also part of the Jcrop download - for the above css, it needs to be in the same folder as the css.  So I suspect either the gif or the css is now out of scope

Comment: Thank you for immediate answer for my question. But I had already the Jcrop.gif in the folder where my css file for jcrop is.

Comment: I checked already in firebug the jcrop.gif in css panel but the image has loaded successfully. I don't think the .gif is the problem..

Comment: I already solved the problem. It is on the version I downloaded in the internet. It seems like the css I downloaded in the internet is latest and what I am reading from Jquery: Novice to Ninja 2nd Edition is older. Hehehe. thanks a lot. You deserve an accepted answer. :-D

Comment: Add this css in your jcrop.css file. It solved the issue for me. thanks. :D